# Getting ssl.SSLError: [X509V3: INVALID_CERTIFICATE] when trying to send email

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, smtplib

I run windows 10 and python 3.11. When I run a pretty standard email sending script I'm getting an SSL error
ssl.SSLError: [X509V3: INVALID_CERTIFICATE] invalid certificate (_ssl.c:4035)

I can run the exact same code from another computer with no issues, I have reinstalled certifi

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall certifi
```

rebooted several times. I can run email connection code without SSL on the same computer.

The only articles I can find online appear to be related to SSL certificates on MAC OS.

Should I be looking for something in MMC?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Projects\webscraping_tours\send_email.py", line 10, in <module>
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Python 3.11.7\Lib\ssl.py", line 775, in create_default_context
    context.load_default_certs(purpose)
  File "D:\Python 3.11.7\Lib\ssl.py", line 596, in load_default_certs
    self._load_windows_store_certs(storename, purpose)
  File "D:\Python 3.11.7\Lib\ssl.py", line 588, in _load_windows_store_certs
    self.load_verify_locations(cadata=certs)
ssl.SSLError: [X509V3: INVALID_CERTIFICATE] invalid certificate (_ssl.c:4035)
```

Comment: It looks like somewhere in a Windows certificate store there is an invalid certificate. Look for something you've added yourself to a one of those stores.

Comment: I found the solution here: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/108721

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here:
https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/108721

In certmgr.msc > intermediate certification authorities>  (filename) 'TPS Self-Signed OAUTH Signing Certificate(PC name)'.  I had 4 copies of this file, some with older PC names.  Apparently they duplicate when the PC is renamed. This is likely where the corruption comes from. I deleted 3 copies of 4 files and rebooted. It did not work until I had deleted the oldest 3 copies.